# How can I configure expiration time of my sessions?

Tags: session, pyramid, session-timeout

My app with Pyramid hasn't got sessions expiration time. How can I configure that?

Comment: The answer depends on what session implementation you are using.

Comment: @MichaelMerickel, i am using authentication pyramid by default.

from pyramid.security import (Allow, Authenticated, Everyone, ALL_PERMISSIONS, authenticated_userid, forget, remember)

http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/api/request.html#pyramid.request.Request.authenticated_userid

Comment: You're talking about authentication things which are not related to how a session operates in Pyramid. Which session factory and which authentication policy are you using?